# How to SSH multiple service with a for in SHELL?

Tags: linux, ssh, script, centos, shell-script

I would like to access some server via SSH, run some commands and exit. Do this for lots of servers.

I know I can do this for one machine only, with this script :

```
ssh **IP** << EOF

chown -R **COMMAND 1**

chown -R **COMMAND 2**

chmod -R 775 **COMMAND 3**

EOF
```

But when I try to put this inside of a FOR in SHELL, keeps saying `line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file`.}

Here is my code for SSH multiple servers:

```
#!/bin/bash

#user already added to group nagios by LDAP

declare -a arr=( **IP1 IP2 IP3** ...)

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
   echo  "Acessing server $i"
   ssh IP << EOF
   chown -R COMMAND 1
   chown -R COMMAND 2
   chmod -R 775 COMMAND 3
   EOF
done
```

Where is my mistake here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash is expecting to see `EOF` at the beginning of a line in your script.  Try removing the indent before `EOF`.

Comment: It works, thank you!
However it prints `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`, should I be worry about this ?

Comment: Not if it works ;) however, to avoid the message you can run the commands without trying to allocate a pty: `ssh hostname 'command1; command2; command3'`.

Comment: great! works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try with newline character after the first EOF and before the last EOF.

Another thing that comes to my mind is that, you can also use pssh (parallel SSH) to do the job. I just don't know if it fits your project.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: I didn't know about `pssh`, I will look into it.
Thank you!